# How to add new calculations to existing table based on text field with multiple entries?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Question: How can I populate the [score [TXT]] columns with the specified calculation? Sometimes the calculations will be based off multiple rows depending on the value in the [game] column.**

I have a table with Metascores and game names, and want to apply some sort of formula that automatically calculates the AVG, MAX, and MIN for the entry. The table above has my desired output. I am using Office 365 - Excel.

**Current table**

| **Metascore** | score AVG | score MAX | score MIN | **game** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87 |  |  |  | Assassin's Creed Odyssey |
| 86 |  |  |  | Assassin's Creed Odyssey |
| 83 |  |  |  | Assassin's Creed Odyssey |
| 66 |  |  |  | Bleeding Edge |
| 62 |  |  |  | Bleeding Edge |

**Desired output**

| **Metascore** | score AVG | score MAX | score MIN | **game** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 87 | 85.3 | 87 | 83 | Assassin's Creed Odyssey |
| 86 | 85.3 | 87 | 83 | Assassin's Creed Odyssey |
| 83 | 85.3 | 87 | 83 | Assassin's Creed Odyssey |
| 66 | 64 | 66 | 62 | Bleeding Edge |
| 62 | 64 | 66 | 62 | Bleeding Edge |

Some titles only occur once, some several times. Is there a formula or script I can apply that loops through the table and applied the calculation, or a different suggestion of an output?

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: If you use Office 365 look into `UNIQUE()`

Comment: Yes, this is Office 365. I will take a look at UNIQUE, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=UNIQUE(E2:E6)` in for instance `E10`
`=AVERAGEIF($E$2:$E$6,$E$10#,A2:A6)` in `A10` and copy to the right.

Or in one go using `LET`:

```
=LET(data,A2:E6, 
     game,INDEX(data,,5),
     unique,UNIQUE(game),
CHOOSE({1,2,3,4,5},
       AVERAGEIF(game, unique,INDEX(data,,1)),
       AVERAGEIF(game, unique,INDEX(data,,2)),
       AVERAGEIF(game, unique,INDEX(data,,3)),
       AVERAGEIF(game, unique,INDEX(data,,4)),
       unique))
```

[image]

Edit:

After the changed description, this is what you need:

In `B2` use: `=AVERAGEIF(E2:E6,E2:E6,A2:A6)`

In `C2` use: `=MAXIFS(A2:A6,E2:E6,E2:E6)`

In `D2` use: `=MINIFS(A2:A6,E2:E6,E2:E6)`

If you'd have your data in two columns (let's say `A20:B20`) and would want a summary elsewhere, you could use the following:

```
=LET(data,A2:B6,
     game,INDEX(data,,2),
     score,INDEX(data,,1),
     unique,UNIQUE(game),
CHOOSE({1,2,3,4},
     unique,
     AVERAGEIF(game,unique,score),
     MAXIFS(score,game,unique),
     MINIFS(score,game,unique)))
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like this is really close to what I'm looking for. This appears to give me the average, but I'm also looking for MIN and MAX, and if possible, filling in the existing table vs creating a new one. I don't mind creating a new table all together if the data is accurate. I will edit my question to include a before and after for clarity.

Comment: Oh, I thought these values where part of the data. In that case it's slightly different.

Comment: See the edit below the original answer

Comment: And a suggestion summary using LET